# How to add suggester component with multiple dictionaries using Config API in Solr?

Tags: solr

As per [Solr guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/config-api.html), adding a suggester component with 1 dictionary using config API is done using the request below:

```
{
    "add-searchcomponent": {
        "name": "suggest",
        "class": "solr.SuggestComponent",
        "suggester": {
            "name": "suggest",
            "lookupImpl": "AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory",
            "dictionaryImpl": "DocumentDictionaryFactory",
            "field": "_suggestField_",
            "suggestAnalyzerFieldType": "suggest_text"
        }
    }
}
```

However, doing the same with multiple dictionary is not documented in the guide.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">cat</str>
        <str name="weightField">price</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">altSuggester</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentExpressionDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="field">product_name</str>
        <str name="weightExpression">((price * 2) + ln(popularity))</str>
        <str name="sortField">weight</str>
        <str name="sortField">price</str>
        <str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_en</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

How do I convert the above XML config to a config API request?

EDIT: I have configured the suggester component with 1 dictionary and here's what the suggest config look like (via config api)

```
"suggest": {
    "name": "suggest",
    "class": "solr.SuggestComponent",
    "suggester": {
        "name": "tags",
        "lookupImpl": "AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory",
        "dictionaryImpl": "DocumentDictionaryFactory",
        "field": "_tagSuggest_",
        "weightField": "price",
        "suggestAnalyzerFieldType": "suggest_text"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what the Config API returns when the suggester is initially configured in the XML file?

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, I've updated the question to include the suggest config. Btw, I also used the config API to configure my suggest component.

Comment: My idea was that if you configure it as XML initially, and then use the config api to retrieve _that_ configuration, it could give you a tip about how (if) it's being supported - maybe you can give a list to the `suggest` or `suggester` keys?

Comment: @MatsLindh, I tried doing a simple but counter-intuitive request and it worked. It turns out that Solr can accept a JSON with properties that have duplicate key (i.e. `suggester`). I'm gonna post it as answer for future references. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>As it turns out, Solr config API can accept a JSON with duplicate keys. We can convert the above suggester XML config to below config API request.</strike>

The correct way to do it is to set `suggester` as an array.

```
{
    "add-searchcomponent": {
        "name": "suggest",
        "class": "solr.SuggestComponent",
        "suggester": [
            {
                "name": "mySuggester",
                "lookupImpl": "FuzzyLookupFactory",
                "dictionaryImpl": "DocumentDictionaryFactory",
                "field": "cat",
                "weightField": "price",
                "suggestAnalyzerFieldType": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "altSuggester",
                "lookupImpl": "FuzzyLookupFactory",
                "dictionaryImpl": "DocumentDictionaryFactory",
                "field": "product_name",
                "weightExpression": "((price * 2)) + ln(popularity)",
                "sortField": "price",
                "storeDir": "suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict",
                "suggestAnalyzerFieldType": "text_en"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When you query the config API, you'll see that the request and the configuration saved are the same.

Thanks to @MatsLindh for suggesting a way to figure this out!